# Entity framework 6.0 with oracle 11

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6

is the Entity framework 6.0 compatible with oracle 11 ?
Will there be support for Entity Framework 6 in managed ODP.NET ? 
Any reliable provider in the market for Entity framework 6.0,Oracle 11 support ?

Comment: I'm coming late to this party for you - but the Oracle 12 Release 2 Beta 3 (which should be final release by the end of the year, they say) does support EF6 (and I've used it against an Oracle 11 database).

Comment: Super cool..Thanks Jason,We will have to see our options to upgrade EF6

Comment: EF5 works out of the box with the Oracle Nuget package for ODP.NET Managed Driver, designer model and everything.   If you are using EF6, you can use their Beta3 driver (downloadable from them) or wait a short bit -- they keep saying "after summer, 2014" - so it should be any day now unless they put the brakes on it.

Comment: Also, to clarify -- those Oracle12 drivers (beta that works with EF6, and the previous revision that works with EF5)  **do** work with Oracle11 -- that's what my database is, 11.2- and they work.

Comment: Thanks for your time Jason.We are planning to upgrade our servers from 11 to 12 c . I will play with it and will get back to ...

Comment: between u are not late in the party :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today [dotConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/editions.html) from Devart should work as far as I investigated ([here](http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-6-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-sqlite-and-salesforce.html)). I don't think the guys from Oracle has reached so far to make ODP.NET compatible to EF6.

Actually I am also working on a project and I am curious about the results.

Comment: I can say I am pretty satisfied with this so far